# How to include a dependency C library in Haskell Stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I want to create a Haskell Stack package that includes another Haskell Stack package as an `extra-dep`. The problematic thing is that the package that i'm trying to include is a binding to some C code, using Haskell's FFI.

If I just `stack unpack`  and `stack build` that package ([HasCacBDD](https://github.com/m4lvin/HasCacBDD)) it works just fine, but when I include it as an `extra-dep` Stack complains about a missing library.

Looking at the `Setup.hs` of that original package, I see that it basically creates an static library called `libHasCacBDD.a` and puts it in the correct folder inside the `.stack-work` path for it to be linked. This library is precisely the one that is giving me an error when I include it in my own project.

Looking carefully at the `.stack-work` folder of my own project, I see that the mentioned `libHasCacBDD.a` is indeed inside the directory hidden in some place. So fortunately, the library is being built correctly but my project cannot find it.

The official [Haskell Stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/faq/#does-stack-also-install-the-systemc-libraries-that-some-cabal-packages-depend-on4) documentation says something about what to do in that case, but I think it is not specific enough to give me a satisfactory answer.

What I need to do is to specify the path where the `libHasCacBDD.a` library is being stored as a `extra-lib-dirs` option. Nevertheless, I do not how to do that in a platform independent way (if i hardcode the path in my computer, it will just work in it and what's the point of doing a package in that case).

I created an [issue on Github](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/4141) with more information about the particulars.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I've handled this in the past with a Makefile that finds the local directory, and wraps my usual stack commands with arguments to use it.

```sh
LIB_DIR :=$(shell dirname $(shell find $(shell stack path --local-install-root) -name libHasCacBDD.a))
ARGS = --extra-lib-dirs ${LIB_DIR}

test:
    stack ${ARGS} test --fast -j4
```

Ugly, but it works.

ETA:
The first line invokes the shell three times:

- `stack path` to find out where packages are being installed
- `find` to locate the specific file you need
- `dirname` to get the directory

The remaining lines pass that directory to `stack` as an extra library directory.  Doing this every time `make` is called avoids putting the path in a file, where it needs to be updated when the compiler or package version change.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, that seems to be useful to be able to move the file once it has been built. I think this solution would not solve the problem because the error i get is when building the project, and it would not build anyway right? Unless i called it inbetween some operation of the build process. I get the feeling that the only way i'm going to be able to do it is inside the ```Setup.hs``` file, as a hook somewhere. Still, the code you provided to me would certainly be useful, i would just need to call it inside the Setup.hs file.

Comment: I think you said that `libHasCacBDD.a` is being built correctly, and put somewhere under your `.stack-work`.  Does adding the path to `extra-lib-dirs` work?  The code I gave locates the file, to help address your concerns about platform portability.